# Result based on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The goal is to understand how to use the formula here in excel
=PRODUCT($I$2:I13)-1
i can't figure out how to output the result based on J column.
How can I calculate this outside of Excel, I have the first(H) and second(I) data.
i need to find J Outside the excel formula

```
row
1.   Col1(H)   Col2(I)   result(J)     Col2(I)fopmula      Col(j)result(formula)
2.   0.00%  100.00%    0.00%          =H2+1               =PRODUCT(I2)-1
3.    1.64% 101.64%    1.64%          =H3+1               =PRODUCT($I$2:I3)-1
4.   0.14%  100.14%    1.78%          =H4+1               =PRODUCT($I$2:I4)-1
5.  (2.26%) 97.74%    (0.51%)         =H5+1               =PRODUCT($I$2:I5)-1
6.  2.37%   102.37%    1.84%          =H6+1               =PRODUCT($I$2:I6)-1
7.  0.53%   100.53%    2.38%          =H7+1               =PRODUCT($I$2:I7)-1
8.  0.07%   100.07%    2.45%          =H8+1               =PRODUCT($I$2:I8)-1
9.  0.88%   100.88%   3.35%           =H9+1               =PRODUCT($I$2:I9)-1
10.  1.29%  101.29%   4.68%           =H10+1              =PRODUCT($I$2:I10)-1
11.  1.98%  101.98%   6.76%           =H11+1              =PRODUCT($I$2:I11)-1
12. 1.54%   101.54%   8.41%           =H12+1              =PRODUCT($I$2:I12)-1
13.  10.25% 110.25%   19.52%          =H13+1              =PRODUCT($I$2:I13)-1
```

Comment: What do you mean "*outside of Excel*"?

Comment: Тhe goal is to calculate it with another tool

Comment: I guess you have the following situation: you have a problem, outside of Excel, and you know how to solve your problem using Excel. This gives two possible solutions: either you export your Excel finding outside Excel (like exporting, using "Save as..."), or you try to launch Excel from your outside environment, and I have the impression you're focussing on the latter solution. Why? What's the problem exporting your Excel results outside of Excel?